# Flex: How to scroll page to bottom?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I have a Flex application, I want to scroll the page to bottom when a button is pressed.
Scroll bars is added by browser, they do not belong to flex app or component.

I can do this by javascript but is there a way to do this with action script?

Thanks.
Enes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Container` class has a `verticalScrollPosition` and a `maxVerticalScrollPosition`. If you set the former to the latter you will scroll the container to the bottom.